# How many connections do Laravel Eloquent model operation create?

Tags: php, database, laravel

As far as I understand, each `DB::` object in Laravel opens new connection and closes it when the operation is finished.

But what with models, especially when I make some changes to them?

For example, if I have

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->setVisible(['id', 'name']);
    // some more operations with data happen here
}
```

I don't do any `save()` or `update()` to these models, just read the data in `foreach`, setting custom visible columns.

How many connections will be created and closed during this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will generate only one query, since `setVisible()` doesn't work with DB, it's just a setter:

```
public function setVisible(array $visible)
{
    $this->visible = $visible;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I was talking about native setVisible, not some my own function: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setVisible

Comment: @YawningMilk in this case it will not create any additional queries.

Comment: thanks a lot! maybe you could also give me a tip, where could I read something useful about connections and stuff?

Comment: @YawningMilk the best way to see how many queries Laravel create for every request is to use [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar). You'll love it.